# Ubuntu 22.04, Gnome search stopped showing Bluetooth, Keyboard, Settings etc

Tags: gnome, 22.04, search

Suddently gnome search started missing lot of apps. When searching bluetooth, it shows some list of font files. SImilary it doesn't show settings, keyboard etc. Please help how to bring those in search result back.